# Congrats to Brian Knoblauch for reaching 9k points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Please take a moment to congratulate @BrianKnoblauch for reaching this great point milestone!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations Brian,

That's a good chunk of rep.  Haven't seen you around much but clearly you've cranked out some answers over the years.

Hope to see you in chat sometime.

Congrats,

Ducatikiller